# Partitioning mysql table on the basis of fulltxt(datatype:text) column

Tags: mysql

I want to partition below mysql table on the basis of `fulltxt field` having datatype is `text`. Here is my table structure.

```
CREATE TABLE links_copy (
  link_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  site_id int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  url varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  fulltxt text,
  indexdate date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (link_id),
  KEY url (url),
  KEY md5key (md5sum),
  KEY fulltext2 (fulltxt(100)),
  KEY indexdate (indexdate)
);
Partition By range(fulltxt)(
PARTITION p0 VALUES IN ('California'),
PARTITION p1 VALUES IN ('City'),
PARTITION p2 VALUES IN ('Council'),
PARTITION p3 VALUES IN ('Meeting'),
PARTITION p4 VALUES IN ('Agenda'));
```

**Question:**
Is it possible to partition on the basis of fulltxt, not on basis of primary key link_id?

Comment: I don't think it's possible as-is, but why do you define `fulltxt` as `text` if the values are just a few characters?

Comment: Hello dnoeth, I am define fulltxt as text because it contains 6 to 7 lines not just a few characters

Comment: Ok, but you try to partition by a single word and based on your expression there might be exactly those 5 words and nothing else. And what if one row contains lines with both `'City'` **and** `'Agenda'`?

Answer (score 0):

Cannot do it.  Syntax errors.  Would not help if you could do it.

Show us the `SELECTs` that you hope to speed up via `PARTITIONing`.  (I will probably point out why `PARTITIONing` will not help any of them.)